# how to implement single sign on in nodebb discussion forum?

Tags: node.js, oauth, nodebb

We have implemented discussion forum using NodeBB. NodeBB requires login in order to start the discussion in the discussion forum.

The problem we are facing is NodeBB discussion forum is having their own login mechanism. but we want single sign-on throughout our application as we have our own login and register mechanism.
Is there any way we can redirect users to an existing site to NodeBB forum without asking them to enter login information again?

Answer (score 0):

If your identity provider supports OpenID Connect, there are a couple of plugins available for NodeBB.

There are instructions to optionally bypass the default NodeBB login page all together.

This plugin should work with any OpenID Connect provider, open an issue if something doesn't work for you.

https://github.com/FusionAuth/nodebb-plugin-fusionauth-oidc